# Excalibur project not showing anything

Tags: javascript, game-engine

My code is supposedly made to show two sprites of buttons (nothing terribly complex (or is it?), but nothing is appearing, not even the blue screen that is supposed to show with only creating the game variable and initiating it. All my code has been made from following the official Excalibur documentation, so what is happening?

The code:

```
var game = new ex.Engine({
width: 1024,
height: 768
});

function loadAssets() 
{
    var loader = new ex.Loader();
    var resources = {
    txGameTitle: new.ex.Texture("icons/GUI/final/"),
    txStartButton: new.ex.Texture("icons/GUI/final/MenuPlayButton.png"),
    txLoadButton: new.ex.Texture("icons/GUI/final/MenuLoadButton.png"),
    txOptionsButton: new.ex.Texture("icons/GUI/final/"),
    txExitButton: new.ex.Texture("icons/GUI/final/"),
    txMenuBackground: new.ex.Texture("icons/GUI/final/"),
    txMenuMusic: new.ex.Sound("icons/GUI/final/")
    };

    for (var loadable in resources)
    {
         if (resources.hasOwnProperty(loadable))
        {
             loader.addResource(resources[loadable]);
        }
    }
}

function startUp()
{
    var StartButton = new ex.Actor.extend({
        onInitialize: function (engine)
        {
            this.addDrawing(txStartButton.asSprite());
        }
    });

    var LoadButton = new ex.Actor.extend({
        onInitialize: function (engine)
        {
            this.addDrawing(txLoadButton.asSprite());
        }
    });

}

function init()
{
    loadAssets();
    startUp();

}

init();

game.start(loader).then(function () {
    console.log("Game started!");
});
```

sorry for the bad formatting.

Answer (score 1):

I think that could be because of a code error. I noticed that right at the end of the file

```
game.start(loader)
```

the *loader* variable is referenced but seems like it is not defined. There is the same variable which created inside *loadAssets* function, but it is a local one. Probably in order to use it, you need to define it above.

```
var loader;

function loadAssets() {
 loader = ...
}

...other code

game.start(loader).then(...
```

Another variant is to define loader outside the *loadAssets* function.

```
var loader = new ex.Loader();

function loadAssets() {
  var resources = {...
}

...other code

game.start(loader).then(...
```

Comment: still only a white screen.